Big Object Record Limits
I have a limit of 1 million Big Object records in my Salesforce Org. Is this limit a total cap for all Big Objects combined, or is it a per Big Object limit? Specifically, if I create 100 Big Objects, does the 1 million record limit apply to each Big Object individually, or is it a cumulative limit across all Big Objects? The total limit seems quite low if it applies to all Big Objects combined.

The 1 million record limit for Big Objects in Salesforce is a cumulative limit across all Big Objects in your org. This means that if you create multiple Big Objects, the total number of records across all of them combined cannot exceed 1 million.
If you need more storage, you can contact Salesforce to discuss increasing this limit. Salesforce offers options to extend the storage capacity for Big Objects, which can be useful if your organization requires more extensive data storage.
